# Working D3 And Crossfilter for generating graph

Tags: csv, graph, d3.js, crossfilter

I am using [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) for performing load test on web site. And JMeter generates output in form of CSV file.

I want to represent this CSV data in graph form. For generating the graph, my teacher suggested using D3 and Crossfilter. But I don't know about these tools.

Can you help me to understand how I might use D3 and Crossfilter for creating graph from CSV file?

Comment: This is far too general.  D3 is amazing and very quick and flexible to get to at least try something.

I'd suggest having a look at the demos (there are literally thousands) and then come back with some more specific questions about more specific problems.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [tutorial on creating a D3 graph from a CSV file](http://thecodingtutorials.blogspot.ie/2012/07/using-csv-and-text-files-with-d3.html). For anything more specific, you'll have to ask a more specific question.